# JOptionPane and comboBox

Tags: java, combobox, joptionpane

I am trying to add a comboBox as a result of previous comboBox selection. Once the user selects "Update" it should open a JOptionPane of another comboBox. How would I go about doing this? As of right now I have a JOptionPane that opens and ask the user to input their selection, however, I am trying to utilize a comboBox instead like the picture below.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ljDs.jpg)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private HashMap<Integer, Student> map = new HashMap<Integer,Student>();
    private JButton processRequest = new JButton("Process Request");
    private JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>();
    private JComboBox<String> comboBox2 = new JComboBox<String>();
    private JLabel label = new JLabel("Choose a request:");
    private JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Id:");
    private JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Name:");
    private JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Major:");
    private JTextField text1 = new JTextField("");
    private JTextField text2 = new JTextField("");
    private JTextField text3 = new JTextField("");

    public GUI(){
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));
        comboBox.addItem("Add");
        comboBox.addItem("Find");
        comboBox.addItem("Update");
        comboBox.addItem("Delete");

        comboBox2.addItem("A");
        comboBox2.addItem("B");
        comboBox2.addItem("C");
        comboBox2.addItem("D");
        comboBox2.addItem("F");

        add(label1);
        add(text1);
        add(label2);
        add(text2);
        add(label3);
        add(text3);
        add(label);
        add(comboBox);
        add(processRequest);
        processRequest.addActionListener(this);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(comboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Add")){
            String str = text1.getText();
            int sid = Integer.parseInt(str);
            String sname = text2.getText();
            String smajor = text3.getText();
            text1.setText("");
            text2.setText("");
            text3.setText("");
            Student student = new Student(sname, smajor);

            if(map.containsKey(sid))
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sid + " is already inserted in the database.");
            else
                map.put(sid,  student);
        }
        else if(comboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Find")){
            String str = text1.getText();
            int sid = Integer.parseInt(str);

            if(map.containsKey(sid)){
                String result = "ID: " + sid + ", " + map.get(sid);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, result);

            }
            else
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sid + " is not found in the database.");
        }
        else if(comboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Update")){

            String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter student ID:");
            int sid = Integer.parseInt(str);

            str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the course grade:");
            char grade = Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(0));

            str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter credit hours:");
            double hours = Double.parseDouble(str);

            if(map.containsKey(sid)){
                map.get(sid).courseCompleted(grade, hours);
            }
            else
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sid + " is not found in the database.");
        }
        else if(comboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Delete")){
            String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter student ID:");
            int sid = Integer.parseInt(str);

            if(map.containsKey(sid))
                map.remove(sid);
            else
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  sid + "is not found in the database.");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println();
        }
        }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        GUI frame = new GUI();
        frame.setTitle("Project 4");
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```